# C - minimax with zobrist not sending right player for the execution

Tags: c, artificial-intelligence, hashtable, alpha-beta-pruning, minmax

I have tried to implement minimax with alpha-beta pruning and zobrist hash for an abalone game (being a beginner), before adding the hash table everything worked fine (no strange behavior and no segmentation faults).
Now the problem is moves that are executed, sometimes are executed for the wrong player . I don't know how or why

`eval_board()`  is my evaluation function.

`AvailableMoves()` Generates a string of characters with all possible moves for current player.

`concat()` Takes care of the concatenation of 2 strings of chars

`StringToMove()` and `MoveToString` : converts an array containing data on the move to a string of chars and vice versa.

`score[hash_id]` is the table that stores my hashes it is a global variable
that is malloced in the main, and I reassign each value to `""` it after every move.

```
  score=(char**)malloc(1948*sizeof(char*));
  for(f=0;f<1948;f++)
    score[f]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
  for(f=0;f<1948;f++)
    sprintf(score[f],"");
```

Here is my code

```
`char* alphaBeta(int8_t deptG,int8_t dept, int16_t alpha, int16_t beta,char* current,int8_t player)
{
    int16_t eval=eval_board();
    char* moves= AvailableMoves(player);
    int hash_id = hashZobrist();
    if(strcmp(score[hash_id],"") && strcmp(substr(current,0,16),substr(score[hash_id],0,16)))
    {
      return score[hash_id];
    }
    if (dept==0 || (int16_t)strlen(moves)==0)
    {
        sprintf(score[hash_id],"%s",current);
        concat(&score[hash_id],ToString(eval));
        return score[hash_id];
    }
    int16_t i=0;
    for (i=0;i<(int16_t)strlen(moves);i+=16)
    {
        execute_move(StringToMove(substr(moves,i,16)),player);
        char* returnString = alphaBeta(deptG,dept-1, alpha, beta,substr(moves,i,16), player*(-1));
        int16_t value = atoi(substr(returnString,16,(int16_t)strlen(returnString)-16));
        undo(StringToMove(substr(moves,i,16)),player);
        if (player==-1){
            if (value<=beta)
            {
              beta=value;
              if (dept==deptG)
              {
                current=malloc(sizeof(char)*16);
                sprintf(current,"%s",substr(returnString,0,16));
              }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (value>alpha)
            {
              alpha=value;
              if(dept==deptG)
              {
                current=malloc(sizeof(char)*16);
                sprintf(current,"%s",substr(returnString,0,16));
              }
            }
            }
        if (alpha>=beta)
        {
            if (player==-1)
            {
              concat(&current,ToString(beta));
              return current;
            }
            else
            {
              concat(&current,ToString(alpha));
              return current;
            }
        }
    }
    if (player==-1)
    {
      concat(&current,ToString(beta));
      return current;
    }
    else
    {
      concat(&current,ToString(alpha));
      return current;
    }
}`
```

PS : As I mentioned I'm a beginner so if you find anything wrong or that could have been done better in my code or any advice really, please let me know.

Comment: What is score[] and where it's allocated? How does substr() work? I fear you have some memory allocation/overwrite problems... Why do you use small integers (int8_t or int16_t)? Compilers won't be faster with a 8bit or 32bit index, when you do not need very large numbers and there is no i/o serialization involved use plain "int".

Comment: how do you compute the zobrist hash? The problem you describe (where moves are executed for the wrong player) makes it sound to me like you should incorporate a variable indicating whose turn it is in the game state when computing the zobrist hash value. This is not necessary in all games, but it is necessary in games where it is possible to reach the exact same game state with the only difference being whose turn it is

Comment: I have edited the post to include how score[] is used, I used small integers because memory is used up pretty fast, I'll try to solve that after the program works fast enough, and for zobrist hashes I just XOR different values in a table `zobristTable[board_cases][player]`

Comment: @RedaDrissi so that's only the board state, correct? Like I mentioned, I suspect you'll want to include another random number that you XOR every time when the turns switch (assuming it's a two-player game). See, for example, how I updated the zobrist hash value in this file: https://github.com/DennisSoemers/SerPrunesALot/blob/master/SerPrunesALot/SerPrunesALot/GameState.cpp

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, so my hash_IDs should depend on the player right?

Comment: yes. Because otherwise you'll store a game state in the transposition table where the first player is allowed to move next, and then later in the search process retrieve the ''same'' game state from the table which is actually not really the same because the second player is allowed to move.

Comment: what about storing moves in `score[hash_id]` in a way that `hash_id` is the evaluation of the board in its current state

Comment: I don't see how that'd work. There'd be many very different game states with equivalent evaluations. Also, the point of using a transposition table is to avoid needing to search deeper to obtain an accurate evaluation if the same search was already done in an earlier part of the tree, so if you already have an evaluation before reading from the table you don't need the table anymore.

Comment: You're right, and what do you think the size of score[] should be?

Comment: that depends on your particular situation, mostly on how much memory you have (typically bigger is better). You'll probably also want to store much more than only scores in your table though. For instance, you'll want to use only some bits of your hash as index into the table (x bits for a table of size 2 to the power x), and the remaining bits (of, say, a 64 bit hash value) to detect collisions. See also section 6.1 of https://github.com/DennisSoemers/SerPrunesALot/blob/master/Report/ISG%20KnightThrough%20Report%20Dennis%20Soemers.pdf for the last time I implemented it.

Comment: Alright thanks, but I tried to separate hashes, still moves are executed for the wrong player

Comment: I'm not sure what else could be wrong at this time. Well, I suspect using an `int hash_id` as index for a score array of only 1948 entries can quickly become problematic, such an index is likely to become invalid. Not sure why that would cause the issue you describe though. Otherwise, it's kinda difficult to tell what's going on, with moves represented as `char*`s and all the hardcoded numbers everywhere... so would take more time to figure out than I have right now, gotta get back to work.

Comment: Any reason you sometimes cast, sometimes not the result of `malloc`? In C you should not. In general: never cast if unnecessary or you don't understand why.

Comment: Actually no particular reason, although I thought casting is better, I'll remove all casts then